# Программа зацикливается

Tags: c++, потоки-данных

```
int* n;
cout << "\n Введите количество элементов массива: ";
auto old_state = cin.rdstate();
cin >> *n;
while ((cin.bad() == false) || (*n <= 0) )
{
    cout << "\n Ввод некорректен!!! "
        << "\n Нужно вести целое положительное число в интервале "
        << "\n от 0 до 100 000" << endl;
    cout << "\n Введите количество элементов массива: ";
    cin.setstate(old_state);
    cin >> *n;
}
```

Comment: Labzov  У вас логика некорректная.. Если пользователь ввел некорректное значение или нажал комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+z  в Windows или Ctrl +d в Unix, что вы предполагаете делать?

Comment: А на что `*n` указывает-то?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение. Вы объявили указатель, правда, не понятно зачем, но не выделили память, которая будет адресуема этим указателем, и куда вы собираетесь ввести данные.

```
int* n;
cout << "\n Введите количество элементов массива: ";
auto old_state = cin.rdstate();
cin >> *n;
```

Нет никакого смысла объявлять указатель вместо переменной целочисленного типа.

Если вы собираетесь вводить только положительные значения, то объявите эту переменную, как имеющую беззнаковый тип. Например

```
unsigned int n;
```

При вводе данных, если был набран неверный символ, то следует очищать буфер. Иначе каждая очередная попытка чтения буфера будет наталкиваться на этот некорректный символ в буфере.

Кроме того у входного потока есть метод `clear`, который сбрасывает ошибочное состояние потока.

Ниже приведена демонстрационная программа, которая показывает, как может быть организован ввод. При желании можно еще добавить проверку на конец входного потока, когда пользователь не желает что-либо вводить, и в этом случае прервать программу, либо присвоить переменной `n` значение 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    const unsigned int MAX_VALUE = 100000;

    int unsigned  n;

    std::cout << "\n Введите количество элементов массива: ";

    while ( not ( std::cin >> n ) || MAX_VALUE < n )
    {
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

        std::cout << "\n Ввод некорректен!!! "
                  << "\n Нужно вести целое положительное число в интервале "
                  << "\n от 0 до " << MAX_VALUE << std::endl;
        std::cout << "\n Введите количество элементов массива: ";
    }

    std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Если последовательно ввести следующие значения

```
a
b
1000000
10
```

то диалог с программой будет выглядеть следующим образом

```
 Введите количество элементов массива: a
 Ввод некорректен!!! 
 Нужно вести целое положительное число в интервале 
 от 0 до 100000

 Введите количество элементов массива: b
 Ввод некорректен!!! 
 Нужно вести целое положительное число в интервале 
 от 0 до 100000

 Введите количество элементов массива: 1000000
 Ввод некорректен!!! 
 Нужно вести целое положительное число в интервале 
 от 0 до 100000

 Введите количество элементов массива: 10
 n = 10
```

Comment: Указатель я использовал, так как эта часть кода была функцией, которая делает запрос параметра. Спасибо за хороший ответ!!!

Comment: @SemyonLabzov Я так и подумал, но что, как говорится, написано пером, то не вырубишь топором.:)

Comment: И у меня еще вопрос возник. Если я буду использовать unsigned int, а пользователь введет отрицательное число, то можно будет ошибку отловить

Comment: @SemyonLabzov Точно так же как и с другим некорректным вводом, будет точно такая же ошибка, то есть недопустимый символ. Вам нет необходимости выделять этот частный случай, так как в своем запросе вы указываете, что надо ввести неотрицательное число.